# Optimization techniques

Tags: optimization, system-design

[image]

In the above diagram, we have a producer and a consumer. The producer takes about 1 unit of time to produce something and the consumer take about 9 units of time (4 to read and compute the data and 5 to write it back to the database). From a design standpoint, what might be my options to ensure that consumer does not start lagging behind? What can I do (like caching, ensure proper indexing in the DB) to make this better?

Comment: What does "synchronous API call" mean? Does that mean the producer will wait until the consumer is done with processing whatever it sent it...? Wouldn't that avoid your problem entirely, while making the thing a bit inefficient?

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen Yes, sorry I missed explaining that. Synchronized means the producer ends up waiting for the consumer to be done. So what can I add to my design to ensure that doesn't happen. Things I can add to this design to make it better.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen Yes, it is inefficient. That is why I'm looking at ways to optimize it and make it efficient.

Comment: Can you move the "compute" to the other JVM?  Then the costs aremuch more balanced.

Comment: The "compute" part is the consumer performing on the read data from SQL Consumer DB. I don't believe moving it to another JVM helps in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the hidden details of what your system is exactly like but the initial suggestion which instantly popped into my mind is to create multiple threads for both consumer and producer and use threadpool to reuse the threads. You must create more threads for consumer than producer as consumer is slow and the control flow is synchronous. You should try to perform tuning to decide what should be the ratio of number of consumer to producer threads so that there will be always some consumer threads available to consume the events created by the producer thread instantly.

Again, I don't know what's the exact requirement. For example, using multiple threads will affect the order of execution of events streams resulting in inconsistency. So if you don't require the events to be processed and persisted in exact order they are coming, you can certainly boost the performance by parallelization (using threadpool).

Good luck!

Comment: Lets assume you are free to add any new components or make any changes you want to this system. Ultimate goal is to make sure consumer does not hold back the system. What would you suggest I do? Multiple threads on the consumer works in freeing up the producer but each thread still takes about 9 units of work to complete. Lets also assume data inconsistency is not an issue.